# AP term multiple of prime number

Tags: algorithms, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

I am having this equation :

```
(a+(n-1)d)%p=0
```

Here a and d can go upto 10^18 and p is prime number upto 10^9 .

How to find the least value of n here?

Example : If a=4 and d=9 with p=11 then here answer is 3.

As (4+18)%11 = 0

Answer (score 0):

You have
$$
a+(n-1)d\equiv0\pmod p
$$
and want to solve for n. You can solve it formally, as though it was an equation, to get
$$
n\equiv1-a/d\pmod p
$$

Now you can use the extended Euclidean algorithm to find $a/d\pmod p$ and substitute.

Comment: is this (a/d)(mod p) or mod p is only with d?

Comment: More precisely, we should assume $p\nmid d$ in the first place! Then as Charles says, extended Euclid gives us $u,v\in\mathbb Z$ with $ud+vp=1$. So finally $-aud\equiv -a\pmod p$ and we can pick $n\equiv 1-au\pmod p$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Please explain.I didnt get you

Comment: @Charles Can i assume it like this : (d-a)/d (mod p) which is also equal to ((d-a)%p*(d^(p-2))%p)%p

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen  Can i assume it like this : (d-a)/d (mod p) which is also equal to ((d-a)%p*(d^(p-2))%p)%p